How to design header with animation between selected tabs in flutter
Hi i want to make a header in flutter like mentioned in the image.

While selecting any of the tab the bottom green line should move with the animation.
Is there any sample code from which i can achieve this ?
Thanks in advance.
The bottom green line of the selected tab should change with animation while changing any of the tab.
